# Плавное переключение страниц и pjax

Tags: javascript, css, animate, pjax

Использую переход по страницам без перезагрузки навигации сайта. Пример [тут](http://pjax.herokuapp.com/). Можно ли реализовать плавный переход при клике на пункты меню? Было бы очень хорошо, если бы была возможность связать анимацию с animate.css. То есть, жмем на ссылку, выбранный блок плавно уползает вправо (по примеру анимации "lightSpeedOut" в "animate.css") после чего идет перезагрузка страницы и выползает новый блок (по примеру анимации "lightSpeedIn" в "animate.css").

Вот код одной из страниц. Понятное дело, что другие страницы имеют ту же структуру, только с разным содержимым контента:

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).pjax('.sidebar ul.nav a', '.content', {
        fragment: '.content'
    });
    $.pjax.defaults.timeout = 2500;
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Title</title>
<script src="/js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.pjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<main>
<section class="middle clr">
<section class="content">
Содержимое страницы
</section>
<aside class="sidebar">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="/index.html"><span>Главная</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/about.html"><span>О нас</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/contacts.html"><span>Контакты</span></a></li>
</ul>
</aside>
</section>
</main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант - у тебя должна работать некая функция которая при клике по меню будет получать url загружаемой страницы, вот примерный псевдо-код

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getPage(newPageUrl){
        // уезжает старый блок страницы
        $('#pageBlock').animate({
            left: '5000px', //или right
            opacity: '0.2'
        });
        // очищаем от прошлого содержимого где то там за краями экрана 
        // и возвращаем блок к примеру за границу экрана справа\слева
        $('#pageBlock').html(""); 
        moveBlockToStartPositionOutsideOfScreen("oldPageBlock");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: loadNewPage.php,
            data: {
                newPageUrl: newPageUrl
            },
            success: function(newHtmlBlock) {
                //заполняем новым содержимым
                $('#pageBlock').html(newHtmlBlock);
                moveBlockToFinalPositionWithAnimate("pageBlock");
            }
         });
    });

    $(".menuBtn").click(function(){
        getPage($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

код написан на коленках, но я бы сделал как то так

Comment: В общем-то с перезагрузкой страниц проблем нет. Скрипт Pjax срабатывает отлично. Вопрос в другом, необходима отсрочка в перезагрузке скрипта и анимация. Все внешние решения, не связанные с основным скриптом игнорируются и при клике сразу происходит загрузка нового контента.

Answer (score 0):

Можно отлавливать [событие по завершении AJAX запроса](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) и тогда запускать анимацию.

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    // Запукаем анимацию...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает при клике на `href(или откуда там у вас ссылки через pjax проталкиваются)` поставить `preventDefault()`, и стригеррить событие, которое запустит анимацию "исчезновения/уползания" текущего контента, сделает сам `pjax`, а затем, по success'у, вернет окно на исходное место, тем же способом?
Что-то навроде:

```
$('href').on('click',function(){ 
    $(document).trigger('content_reload_start');//Инициируем событие начала "перехода"
    return false;//вариант preventDefault'a;
}
$(document).on('content_reload_start',function(){//Хэндлим событие начала "перехода"
    $(this).find('#your_content_container').fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).pjax({ //Начинаем, собственно, сам "переход"
        ... //тут хэндлим сам переход, отправляем запрос, парсим ответ, меняем контент, etc.
    }).done(function(){//Я не в курсе, есть ли там свойство success, или ему подобное, но через ajax тот же вариант решения, получится идентично
        $(document).trigger('content_reload_finish'); //Инициируем событие завершения "перехода"
    })
)
$(document).on('content_reload_finish',function(){ //Хэндлим событие завершения "перехода"
    $(this).find('#your_content_container').fadeIn('fast');
})
```

Сразу хотелось бы отметить непровереность кода, *призванного* только чтобы *передать суть*.